# securing client/server communication

Tags: ssl, client-server, oauth2

I have special environment which requires that I think security a bit out of the box.

Components involved:

A web service which requests data from a gateway, processes it and sends it to web clients.
A gateway service which queries the data from a database backend.

A PKI infrastructure does not exist.

The problem is how to make the communication between the web server and the gateway reasonably secure. Communication between the web server and the clients and between the gateway and the backend is out of scope.

Problem: the web service code must be considered insecure since it is written in plain text PhP. The gateway service is written in a "compiled" language, so it would be possible (though not recommended ...) to store a reasonably obfuscated common secret inside.

What concepts do exist for such a scenario to establish an authenticated and encrypted secure channel, preferredly through SSL, assuming that all communication always origins at the web server.

(Someone already threw "Use OAuth" into the discussion, but I don't see the point, since I'd have to store the OAuth credentials/Access tokens somewhere in PhP --> I don't see how this can resolve the problem)

Comment: Hint: what I think could *somehow* work, the Gateway OS has the tool to create self-signed certificates, that there should be a way to utilize these.

How about the Gateway crating two certificates: one for itself, and one for the webserver, where it has to be imported/installed. It should then be possible to establish a secure channel via SSL, shouldn't it?

Comment: Is the web service hosted on an untrusted server? Is there a risk of server admins stealing the secrets?

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a VPN, or even a SSH tunnel between the web service and the gateway. This is *literally* the entire point of a VPN - despite all the crappy sponsored ads. I don't see how oauth would solve the problem.

You also wouldn't need to alter the application on either side since you're tunneling unencrypted data through an encrypted channel. The question is a little high level to suggest a specific solution but this seems the way to do it.

Comment: Wouldn't this approach just delegate the problem to "someone else"? To set up the VPN I'd need to setup and maintain a common VPN secret somewhere in a "safe space".

I have control over the PhP code, and the gateway service code, and I'd prefer a solution which is established between those two.

Otherwise ... yes, this approach would resolve the problem.